# Firebase unresponsive on auth (signInWithEmailAndPassword)

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, remix.run

I am using Remix framework and initializing firebase on node in a file called auth.server.js.
This code worked fine but now I have upgraded to Remix v2 and upgraded firebase to 10.7.2.
When I run now, it gets stuck on signInWithEmailAndPassword with no error or failure.
Just becomes unresponsive. I have tried everything almost !! but no resolution.

If I probe auth, I can see it has access to config but inside errorFactory error

> errors: {
> 'dependent-sdk-initialized-before-auth': 'Another Firebase SDK was initialized and is trying to use Auth before Auth is initialized.
> Please be sure to call `initializeAuth` or `getAuth` before starting
> any other Firebase SDK.'
> }

```
  const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "..."
};
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

my signin code is

```
async function signIn(email, password) {
 
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  let result = null;
  
  try {
   result = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error signin ", error);
    result = error
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This apparently was a problem with the latest Remix version 2.5.1 . This could be a bug.

I have tried the same with a different remix template https://github.com/remix-run/remix/tree/main/templates/unstable-vite and it works.

```
npx create-remix@latest --template remix-run/remix/templates/unstable-vite
```